# MFC librarys in sql console app

Tags: c++, sql, mfc, linker, libraries

I am developing in app that will insert an blob file in a database .I am using **ODBC** for connecting to the database .
      I also need to use some MFC libraries .So my problem is in order to use the MFC libraries i changed in `proget->Config`. `Setting->General->Use MFC in a shared DLL`, but when i do this i get the this link errors :

```
InsertBlob.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SQLFreeHandle@8 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall ODBC::InternalConnect(char *)" (?InternalConnect@ODBC@@QAE_NPAD@Z)
InsertBlob.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SQLDriverConnect@32 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall ODBC::InternalConnect(char *)" (?InternalConnect@ODBC@@QAE_NPAD@Z)
```

I have posted only two of them but there are 12 in total.
If i change the settings back to Use standard windows libraries the link errors disappear but i cannot use CString CFile etc.

Is there any way to use them the two of them in the same app ? I am an c++ novice .

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "Use MFC in a shared DLL" I also have the following files listed in Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies:

odbc32.lib
odbccp32.lib

These files are from the Windows SDK, so the path to these files will probably be something like:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\version???\Lib\

Comment: Thanks . It works now . I just added the libraries in the linker options and give the path to the libraries.